# JNI What is the method descriptor for char [] (char array)?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

My JAVA class code snippet .I want to access getReg_chal() method from my C file using JNI:

```
public char[] getReg_chal() {
        return reg_chal;
    }
```

My C file doing some jni operation:

```
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, info, "getReg_chal()", "()I");

mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, info, "getReg_chal()", ***);
```

I want to know the method descriptor for my char[]. Writing "()I" gives me bogus method descriptor error since ()I is used for Int. What would i fill in ***.
Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature would be "`()[C`" .

You can read about the details [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html#65751) and [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html#70113).

To call the method using the method id, you'd just write something like

```
jobject obj = ... // This is the object you want to call the method on
jcharArray arr = (jcharArray) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);
int count = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
jchar* chars = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, arr, 0);
// Here, "chars" is a C pointer to an array of "count" characters. It's NOT
// going to be 0-terminated, so be careful! Here's where you would do your
// logging or whatever. One possible way to do this is by turning the `jchar`
// array into a proper 0-terminated character string:
char * message = malloc(count + 1);
memcpy(message, chars, count);
message[count] = 0;
LOGD("NDK:LC: [%s]", message);

// When you're done you must call this!
(*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, arr, chars, 0);
```

Comment: After changing the method signature the bogus method error is gone but GetMethodId function is not able to recognise getReg_chal() in JAVA. Its throwing error :  DEBUG/dalvikvm(1365): GetMethodID: method not found: Lcom/rohan/RegisterInfo;.getReg_chal():()[C.. Can you help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't notice that before; those parentheses shouldn't be there. The argument is just the method name, "getReg_chal", no parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Ernest for pointing that out. Can you help me with 1 last thing. I want to store and print the value that getreg_chal() returns. Can you help me how i will store that value in my C file. and then if possible LOG it with LOGD in JNI.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer. I'm still facing problem in viewing the output. Do we need to convert jchar to char? or is it something else . My Code :
int count = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
jchar* chars = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, arr, 0);
int i =0;
for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
{

      LOGD("NDK:LC: [%c]",chars[i]);
}

(*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, arr, chars, 0)
Please suggest someway to take teh LOG properly.

Comment: Well, first, that loop iterates one time more than it is allowed to -- the condition must be `i == count`, not `i <= count`. I don't know what "LOGD" is, but it looks like `printf()`, so I'll assume that's how it works. I will edit my answer one more time, so go have a look.

Comment: You are correct LOGD is same as printf. I tried your suggested approach and i'm getting blank output :
NDK:LC [ ] .... I'm sending char[] regchal={123,234}; from java..