# JNI: call Java method with "()[C" signature

Tags: java, java-native-interface

There is Java class with `getLong()` and `getCharArray()` methods and I have jobject link to this class.

This code

```
jclass clsData = env->GetObjectClass(data);
jmethodID getVal = env->GetMethodID(clsData, "getLong", "()J");
jlong x = env->CallLongMethod(data, getVal);
```

give me access to long value returned by `getLong()`.

```
jclass clsData = env->GetObjectClass(data);
jmethodID getVal = env->GetMethodID(clsData, "getCharArray", "()[C");
???
```

How to get access to character array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the char array like this way this is simple snippet from another post the complete post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7417254/760489)

```
jobject obj = ... // This is the object you want to call the method on
jcharArray arr = (jcharArray) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, getVal);
int count = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
jchar* chars = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, arr, 0);
```